# Is passing the entire state down the react component a good pattern?

Tags: functional-programming, reactjs, flux

The [Flux documentation](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#views-and-controller-views) says that:

> We often pass the entire state of the store down the chain of views in a single object, allowing different descendants to use what they need. In addition to keeping the controller-like behavior at the top of the hierarchy, and thus keeping our descendant views as functionally pure as possible, passing down the entire state of the store in a single object also has the effect of reducing the number of props we need to manage.

In this pseudo code (illustrating the passing of the whole store as suggested by the Flux docs), the interfaces of the components don't seem to be very *well defined*.

```js
function header (state) {
    profileLink(state);
    navigation(state);
}

function postList (state) {
    ul(state);
}

function footer (state) {
    div(state.copyright);
}

function rootComponent () {
    var state = getState();
    header(state);
    postsList(state);
    footer(state)
}
```

Isn't the following example (with more specific interface of the components) more in accordance with the *functional programming* paradigm?

```js
function header (userName, navigationItems) {
    profileLink(username);
    navigation(navigationItems);
}

function postList (posts) {
    ul(posts);
}

function footer (copyright) {
    div(copyright);
}

function rootComponent () {
    var state = getState();
    header(state.user.name, state.navigation.items);
    postsList(state.posts);
    footer(state.copyright);
}
```

The question is: **Isn't the passing of the whole state down the component hierarchy an anti pattern?**

Answer (score 0):

I think what he means is sometimes is convenient to pass the entire state **of one specific store** down the children. It makes sense if all the children are related to the store. For example:

```js
function rootComponent(userState, bookState){
  bookTitle(bookState);
  bookDescription(bookState);
  bookPrice(bookState);
}

bookTitle(bookState) {
  div(bookState.title)
  div(bookState.author)
}

bookDescription(bookState) {
  div(bookState.description)
}

bookPrice(bookState) {
  div(bookState.price)
}
```

So, as you can see, I'm not passing the whole state of the app but all the state coming from the book store is being sent packed to all the children related with this store